# How to parse the complete link in the url query string?

Tags: javascript, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom, urlsearchparams

URL: `https://n9hon.csb.app?name=netflix&url=https://localhost?apikey=123&code=321`

code:

```js
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function useQuery() {
  const {search} = useLocation();
  const query = new URLSearchParams(search);
  console.log('name: ', query.get('name'))
  console.log('url: ', query.get('url'))
  return query
}
```

Output:

```
name:  netflix 
url:  https://localhost?apikey=123
```

As you can see, the `code` parameter is lost. I expect the value of `url` parameter should be `https://localhost?apikey=123&code=321`.

package version:

```
"react-router-dom": "5.2.0"
```

Comment: The `url` value should be escaped so that `&` will be `&amp;`. `https://n9hon.csb.app?name=netflix&url=https://localhost?apikey=123&amp;code=321`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you haven't encoded the URI components. you can use `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` functions to solve your problem. Before push to the route encode the URL and after receiving you can decode it.

Note: Please consider that decoding is not necessary because, `new URLSearchParams(search).get('key')` command will automatically decode the component.

```
// In navigating component

const history = useHistory();

return (
    ...
    <button onClick={() => history.push(`/?name=netflix&url=${encodeURIComponent('https://localhost?apikey=123&code=321')}`)}>
        Go to link
    </button>
    ...
)
```

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function useQuery() {
  const {search} = useLocation();
  const query = new URLSearchParams(search);
  console.log('name: ', query.get('name'))    // name: netflix 
  console.log('url: ', query.get('url'))      // url: https://localhost?apikey=123&code=321 
  return query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, but your input URL is wrong.

If you use:

```
https://n9hon.csb.app?name=netflix&url=https://localhost?apikey=123&code=321
```

Your browser will read it as

```
Protocoll
https:
                Top Level Domain
                 .app
             Domain
              csb
      Sub-Domain
        n9hon
                         Params
                     ?name=netflix&url=https://localhost?apikey=123&code=321
```

What is OK, so far, but then stuff goes down the drain:

```
                        Param 1
                      name=netflix
                                          Param 2
                                   url=https://localhost?apikey=123
                                                                     Param 3
                                                                    code=321
```

If you want to get Param2 and Param 3 read as one Param, you need to get rid of the & (and to be clean also of the ? : = and /)

https://n9hon.csb.app?name=netflix&url=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3Fapikey%3D123%26amp%3Bcode%3D321

In your code you can easily do this by [encodeURI(uri)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) and revert it via [decodeURI(enc)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp)